# TensorFlow Lite conversion error when deployed to microcontroller

Tags: python, tensorflow, arduino, tflite

I created a Keras model using the [transfer learning tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning). I then used the quantization and converter to produce an array of bytes for my Arduino nano sense with the ArduCam 2MP Plus camera:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  repr_ds = ds_rep.unbatch()
  def representative_data_gen():
    for i_value, o_value in repr_ds.batch(1):
      yield [i_value]
  converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(modelDir_fine)
  converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
  converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
  converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
  converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
  converter.representative_dataset = tf.lite.RepresentativeDataset(representative_data_gen)
  tfl_model = converter.convert()

  open("model_alt.tflite", "wb").write(tfl_model)

!apt-get update && apt-get -qq install xxd
!xxd -i model_alt.tflite > converted_model_alt.cc
```

Using [this Arduino code example](https://projecthub.arduino.cc/anaferraz/embedded-machine-learning-for-person-detection-ee255f) to test my board and camera, which worked. I then modified the byte array with my own. This gave me the error “Invoke() called after initialization failed”. Further investigation adding a print out in this section:

```
void loop() {
  delay(30*1000);
  // Get image from provider.
  if (kTfLiteOk != GetImage(error_reporter, kNumCols, kNumRows, kNumChannels,
                            input->data.int8)) {
    TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "Image capture failed.");
  }
  
  //Added print out here 
  TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "Bad input tensor, size. %d", input->dims->size);    

  // Run the model on this input and make sure it succeeds.
  if (kTfLiteOk != interpreter->Invoke()) {
    TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "Invoke failed.");
  }
```

produced the value 2113404085. The same line with the original byte array produced 4.

Putting my tflite file into [Netron](https://netron.app) showed my input to be (1, 224, 224, 3) shape with int8 data type.

[My Netron model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPVsa.png)

[Netron model from example byte array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nsK4.png)

I have tried a simpler conversion using:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(modelDir_fine)
  converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
  tfl_model = converter.convert()

  open("model_alt.tflite", "wb").write(tfl_model)

!apt-get update && apt-get -qq install xxd
!xxd -i model_alt.tflite > converted_model_alt.cc
```

Which produced this Netron model with float32 data type.
[Netron float32 data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB3rS.png)

I then changed the `alignas(8)` to `aligns(32)` in the arduino code which didnt change the outcome of the print out.

It seemed to me like there could have been an error between data types.

Can anyone explain where my conversion may have gone wrong?